# PHP-Build - Building PHP 5.3.28 erro

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I am trying to install PHP 2.3.28 using php-build (https://github.com/CHH/php-build) in Linux Mint 16 (Ubuntu) but it does not compile. I am using php-build because I need to have multiple versions of php on my machine.

I am using this command:

> php-build -i development 5.3.28 ~/local/php/5.3.28

After solving several errors of missing packages, an error is happening that I cannot identify.

See [the full log](http://pastebin.com/x5ZxNkQd).

I need some hint to solve this problem.

==UPDATE==

After adding the following lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb php53.dotdeb.org all stable
deb-src php53.dotdeb.org stable all
```

And run the command:

```
apt-get build-dep php5
```

I finally succeeded compile without any problems using php-build.

Now I will install php-version to easily switch between versions.

Comment: "an error".... so we should read through that wall of log text to try and guess which "error" you're talking about?

Comment: Actually there is no specific error message. Only warnings. 

I corrected several errors, one of them was the lack of PHP_ARCHIVE PEAR package. The problem occurred after installing it with the command:
> sudo pear install-f PHP_Archive 

I believe the last 3 lines are the most important: 
>PEAR package PHP_Archive: API Version: 1.0.0 (stable). 
>PEAR package PHP_Archive: / home / luiz / pear / share / pear. 
>PEAR package PHP_Archive: / home / luiz / pear / share / pear / PHP / archive.php. 

After them, the build is simply interrupted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use different version of php use [xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) for development and testing.
Install different versions of xampp to different folders and switch to needed version with /opt/lampp symlink.

You can get different xampp versions for linux [here](http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/xampp/XAMPP%20Linux/)

opt directory structure will looks like

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   16 Jan 27 07:10 lampp -> /opt/lampp_1.7.7
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4096 Sep 19  2011 lampp_1.7.7
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep 19  2012 lampp_1.8.1
drwxr-xr-x 30 root root 4096 Dec  8 16:26 lampp_1.8.2_x86_64
drwxr-xr-x 30 root root 4096 Dec  2 11:26 lampp_1.8.3_x86_64
```